# SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to Owin (Window)

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

It is my first time working with spatial data. Let's say that I have a point dataset that contains addresses of criminals in nyc. I also obtained a shapefile of new york city zipcodes. My goals is to define a window of my criminal point dataset so I can start doing point analyses. My understanding is that first I need to create a single polygon(owin) of nyc from my multipolygon nyc data.

```
# New york city polygon  
nyc1 <- readOGR(".", "ZIP_CODE_040114") 
> class(nyc1)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
> proj4string(nyc1)
[1] "+proj=lcc +lat_1=40.66666666666666 +lat_2=41.03333333333333 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
nyc1 <- as(nyc1, "SpatialPolygons") # remove the attributes 
nyc  <- as(nyc1, "owin") 
class(nyc)
[1] "owin"
> print(nyc)
window: polygonal boundary
enclosing rectangle: [913129, 1067494.3] x [120020.86, 272710.95] units
```

When I plot nyc a map of nyc with the zipcodes is created and not a single polygon (something went wrong).

```
# Criminal point data 
ss1  <- as(sssf, "Spatial") # Create Spatial* object
> proj4string(ss1)
[1] "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs"
ss <- as(ss2, "ppp")      # Create ppp object
marks(ss)  <- NULL # spatstat remove marks or remove attirbutes
> class(ss)
[1] "ppp"
> print(ss)
Planar point pattern: 172 points
window: rectangle = [-74.171, -73.72929] x [40.57369, 41.50421] units
```

Then assign window.

```
Window(ss) <- nyc
```

When I plot the ss object I only see a map of nyc with zipcodes and not the points. What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit hard to help with when we don't have access to the original objects `nyc1` and  `sssf`. Is everything in the same coordinate reference system (CSR)? If you cannot provide the data then at least show the output of `print(nyc)` and `print(ss)` (before assigning the new window).

Comment: Hi @EgeRubak, thanks for taking the time to write back, I made some changes in my post with the detailed you requested. I noticed that the CSR are different but even when I change them, I have the same issue. nyc1 <- spTransform(nyc1, CRS("+init=epsg:4238")) ss1 <- spTransform(ss1, CRS("+init=epsg:4238"))

Comment: From the output you show it is clear that things aren't going to match. The coordinates of the region are in the range `[913129, 1067494.3] x [120020.86, 272710.95]` and the coordinates of the points look like they may be directly in latitude and longitude in the range `[-74.171, -73.72929] x [40.57369, 41.50421]`. Try to remake the output with everything transformed to the same CSR. And please use a CSR that makes sense otherwise I don't know what happens. From a quick Google search it looks like EPSG 4238 is a reference system covering Indonesia, so it is probably not a good choice for NYC.

Comment: @EgeRubak Thanks for the help. The problem was my point dataframe CRS- it was incorrect. I changed it and it worked. Thank you again!